# how can I find the index for each time a char appears in a string (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, string, char

Hi I'm trying to identify the index of a specific char for every time it is located in a string as well as providing the number of times it is detected.

One way I thought of it was basically using finding the number of times it is in a string using `(str.replace(/[^char]/g, "").length)` and then using `str.lastIndexOf("char")` and  creating a new string after deleting the characters from that index onward and checking it again until I dont find any.

However I don't think this is the most effective way of doing it , so please let me know if you have a better way?

let say: `var str = "123456789017899199999100001"` and we need the **index** of each 1 and how many times it is found in the string.

Comment: `str.match(/1/g).length` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a hash table for the values and their indices. Then take the length of the array as count.

```js
var string = "123456789017899199999100001",
    positions = Object.create(null);
    
[...string].forEach((v, i) => (positions[v] = positions[v] || []).push(i));

console.log(positions[1]);
console.log(positions[1].length);
console.log(positions);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Solution for any string.

```js
var string = "123456789017899199999100001",
    positions = [],
    index = -1,
    search = "99";
    
while ((index = string.indexOf(search, index + search.length)) !== -1) {
    positions.push(index);
}

console.log(positions);
console.log(positions.length);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , this is a nice way of doing it . how can I modify it lets say if I wanted to check for each time 99 was found ?

Comment: what is the wanted result of it?

Comment: the starting index of where each 99 is detected and the number of times 99 was found

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp for such task is overkill, you are right, it can be done simpler way lineary traversing the string:

```
function count(str, char) {
    var rval = {indices:[], count:0};
    for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === char) {
            rval.indices.push(i);
            rval.count++;
        }
    }
    return rval;
}
```

then for your string it would produce:

```
count(str,'1') // {indices:[0,10,15,21,26],count:5}
```

you can also simply return array of indices and its length is total count of occurrences